# Incorrect page number position on ToC page 2 only

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am having an issue where my Table of Contents is so long that it goes onto a second page, but the page number then mysteriously jumps from the bottom center of the page to the upper right corner for JUST the second page of my ToC.  I can't have just that one page's number there.  It needs to be in the bottom center like the others.

The biggest issue that I have is that I have to use a unique document class type for my university's thesis requirements.

This is the section of the code from that class' document about the toc.

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\chapter*{\centerline{Table of Contents}
 \@mkboth{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
% \contentsline{chapter}{\underline{Section}}{\underline{Page}}
 \@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

My actual thesis document code simply looks like this:

```
\pagenumbering{roman}%%% Begin Roman Numeral Numbering
\include{MyAbstract}%Abstract Page
\newpage
\tableofcontents % Table of Contents Page
```

Why is it suddenly doing this for only the second page of the ToC?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you select code and click the button marked `{}` above the text field, it will be highlighted as you see from my edit.

Answer (score 2):

`\pagestyle{plain}` puts the page number centered in the footer. This is usually the page style for the first page of a chapter (or table of contents).
The standard classes are using the page style `plain` as default. In your case there is probably another page style active (explicitly set or implicitly by the class). If the whole document should use page style `plain` put

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

in the preamble and remove the other page style settings.

If only the table of contents should use page style `plain` (why?), then
it can be done by a local change, e.g.:

```
\begingroup
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \tableofcontents
  \cleardoublepage
\endgroup
```

Comment: but, if i remember correctly, `\pagestyle{plain}` doesn't have running heads, and that's implicitly required by the ise of `\markboth` in the (incomplete) example.